# Android - Error inflating text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I know there are a bunch of similar questions on stackoverflow.
But none of these solve my problem.

It's not about theme settings nor resource not found.
And I didn't load large images in this layout(all of the backgrounds are from drawable xml).
All the attributes have accurate values, including namespace declaration.
It just throws this exception randomly.
Looks like an android bug.

It happens on Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P, HTC_A9u, ASUS_Z012, etc.
I'm using API 25, support library 25.0.1, build tools 25.0.2.

It starts reporting this exception after I change to use API 25.

There are 20 similar nodes in the layout with a `ScrollView`.
And a `Fragment` holds this layout.
I initialize it with fragment transaction, then put it in a `DrawerLayout`.

The layout node:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?theme.mainMenuItemBackground"
            android:layout_below="@+id/otherHolder">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aboutCapital"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/my_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="?theme.titleColor"
                    android:text="A"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aboutName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/aboutCapital"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_item_title"
                    android:textColor="?theme.titleColor"
                    android:text="About"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It also happens on `ScrollView` or something like `<unknown>`.

Error logs(`TextView`):

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #813: Binary XML file line #813: Error inflating class TextView
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2665)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #813: Binary XML file line #813: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #813: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference
android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledStringForCookie (AssetManager.java:306)
android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt (TypedArray.java:1217)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt (TypedArray.java:1203)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList (TypedArray.java:526)
android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:1080)
android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:704)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init> (AppCompatTextView.java:62)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init> (AppCompatTextView.java:58)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1017)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1076)
android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView (LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:192)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:769)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
com.example.myapp.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView (MainMenuFragment.java:306)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2087)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1113)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1277)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2154)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:181)
com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity.onStart (LauncherActivity.java:2193)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6696)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2628)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Error logs(`<unknown>`)

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1051: Binary XML file line #1051: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2666)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2727)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1478)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6121)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:876)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1051: Binary XML file line #1051: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1051: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Constructor.java)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:430)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:717)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:785)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
com.example.myapp.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView (MainMenuFragment.java:306)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2087)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1113)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1277)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2154)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:181)
com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity.onStart (LauncherActivity.java:2193)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6699)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2629)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2727)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1478)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6121)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:876)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference
android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledStringForCookie (AssetManager.java:306)
android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt (TypedArray.java:1217)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt (TypedArray.java:1203)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:923)
android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4202)
android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:579)
android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init> (RelativeLayout.java:248)
android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init> (RelativeLayout.java:244)
android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init> (RelativeLayout.java:240)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Constructor.java)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:430)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:717)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:785)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
com.example.myapp.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView (MainMenuFragment.java:306)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2087)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1113)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1277)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2154)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:181)
com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity.onStart (LauncherActivity.java:2193)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6699)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2629)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2727)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1478)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6121)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:876)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

Error logs(`ScrollView`):

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2665)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Constructor.java)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:430)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:717)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:785)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
com.example.myapp.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView (MainMenuFragment.java:288)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2087)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1113)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1277)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2154)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:181)
com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity.onStart (LauncherActivity.java:2196)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6696)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2628)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference
android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledStringForCookie (AssetManager.java:306)
android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt (TypedArray.java:1217)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt (TypedArray.java:1203)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:923)
android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal (View.java:5133)
android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4660)
android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:579)
android.widget.FrameLayout.<init> (FrameLayout.java:92)
android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:180)
android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:176)
android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:172)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Constructor.java)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:430)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:717)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:785)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
com.example.myapp.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView (MainMenuFragment.java:288)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2087)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1113)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1277)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2154)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:603)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:181)
com.example.myapp.LauncherActivity.onStart (LauncherActivity.java:2196)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6696)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2628)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Same issue for me. It's a random TextView in my layout that's causing it. There's nothing different or special about it. Have you found a work around?

Comment: No, I haven't. But it gets better after I put `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` According to this document https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is:

```
android:textColor="?theme.titleColor"
```

YOu should change to `@color/yourcolor` or a hex color

Comment: I have different theme settings. They all use different colors. Why do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Do you try my answer? Can you post your `?theme.titleColor`?

Comment: I can't try your answer, because i'm using theme to apply all colors, backgrounds, etc. `<item name="theme.titleColor">@color/list_item_title_color</item>`

Comment: Why you don't  use `@color/list_item_title_color`??? If no error, you code is error at `android:textColor="?theme.titleColor"`

Comment: Because different theme uses different colors. As I said, it also happens on ScrollView or something like <unknown> and it doesn't happen every time. So I don't think it really matters whether I choose to use `@color/list_item_title_color` or not. Seriously, what's wrong with the `?theme.titleColor`?

Comment: Users can change to use different theme in my app by the way.